# DataGrid Material UI getRowClassName not working on Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datagrid, material-ui

I am trying to add a class based on the value of each row in a `DataGrid` component. However, I get the following error form **TypeScript** when I try to use `getRowClassName` on the component:

```
    Type '{ rows: any[]; getRowClassName: (params: any) => string; columns: GridColDef[]; pagination: true; page: number; error: ApolloError; pageSize: number; hideFooterPagination: boolean; ... 6 more ...; componentsProps: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<GridComponentProps, "disableMultipleSelection" | "disableMultipleColumnsFiltering" | "disableMultipleColumnsSorting" | ... 5 more ... | "options"> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>'.
      Property 'getRowClassName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<GridComponentProps, "disableMultipleSelection" | "disableMultipleColumnsFiltering" | "disableMultipleColumnsSorting" | ... 5 more ... | "options"> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>'.
```

I am using the function like this:

```tsx
<DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    getRowClassName={(params) => (
        `my-datagrid-theme--custom-${params.getValue(params.row.something, 'false')}`
    )}
    columns={columns}
    pagination
    page={page}
    error={error}
    paginationMode="server"
    onPageChange={handlePageChange}
    loading={loading}
/>
```

How can I resolve that issue?

Comment: What version of `@material-ui/data-grid` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade to the latest version to fix this issue